# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2 during RandomUndersampling

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, imblearn

For one of my datasets, I have a data imbalance problem as the minority class has very few samples compared to the majority class. So I want to balance the data by undersampling the majority class. When I am trying to use RandomUnderSamples from imblearn package on a 3D array and I have an error

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

The features in the data which are in 3D format

```
train['X'].shape
(276216, 101, 4)
```

The input labels

```
train['y'].shape
(276216, 1)
```

When I try to randomly undersample data when I run this

```
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
undersample = RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy='majority')

X_train_under, y_train_under = undersample.fit(train['X'], train['y'])
```

I get the above error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Could you please post the full StackTrace? 2. Can you reproduce the error with a minimal example that contains everything necessary for us to reproduce it ourselves with the code you provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function expects 2D arrays to be passed as arguments. Reshape your data and you'll be fine. Also, you will have to call `fit_resample` as per [docs](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html).

```
X = train['X'].reshape(train['X'].shape[0], -1) 
X_train_under, y_train_under = undersample.fit_resample(X, train['y'])
```